# How can global menu / HUD be fixed for Audacity in 16.04?

Tags: unity, hud, globalmenu, audacity

Applications like this become very time consuming without the HUD. But lack of global menu seems to be causing this. It *did* work on first installation but now it's gone. Reinstalling can make it work for a few minutes (that is, the global menu appears and is functional, as well as HUD) but not long term.

I can't find a workaround anywhere. Please help!

[image: Audacity on 16.04 - No global menu intergration]

Answer (score 2):

I've finally found a solution to this, although by accident. Launching audacity via pasuspender actually fixes the HUD menu issue for some reason. And it does it consistently, every time. So by launching Audacity with the command:

```
pasuspender audacity
```

the globalmenu/HUD is reinstated. Also, Audacity is very stable as a result.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to insert the suggested command by @TenLeftFingers in Audacity launcher that found the reason: HUD is disabled on purpose.

To enable it, if you have **root** access, you can edit the original file:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/audacity.esktop
```

Find the `Exec` line and remove `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0`, so that it will be like this:

```
Exec=env audacity %F
```

Then, save and exit.

**Without root** or to preserve against changes through updates, you can save the desktop file under `~/.local/share/applications/` (in which '~' represents your home) – if it doesn't exist don't hesitate to create it.